# Does solidity create unique outputs every time it compiles same exact code?

Tags: solc, abi, multisignature

Is there any difference if I compile everytime I want to deploy another multisig wallet.
Or I can just deploy another multisig wallet using the same compiled data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is there any difference if I compile everytime I want to deploy another multisig wallet.

*No, provided you haven't changed anything in the contract. In case if you haven't changed anything in the contract and try compiling it again, truffle returns the below result*

```
> truffle compile
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
```

- Or I can just deploy another multisig wallet using the same compiled data?

*Yes, you can use the same compiled bytecode to deploy multiple instances of MultiSig Wallet*

- Does solidity create unique outputs every time it compiles same exact code?

*No*

Comment: There is nothing in the question about Truffle though.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the same source-code with the same compiler version yields the same byte-code.